# Read text from a text file with specific pattern

Tags: c#

Hi there I have a requirement where i need to read content from a text file. The sample text content is as below.

```
Name=Check_Amt
Public=Yes
DateName=pp
Name=DBO
```

I need to read the text and only extract the value which comes after `Name='What ever text'`.

So I am expecting the output as `Check_Amt`, `DBO`

I need to do this in C#

Comment: It's just a plain text file or an xml, json file?

Comment: Is it all one line (like you show) or is it one assignment per line. Consider using the `{}` button to format your example

Comment: So what have you tried? Read the file line by line, and if it starts with `Name=`, then print all text for that line after the fifth character?

Comment: Its a text files and each content is a separate line

Comment: Did you already try opening the file and reading the lines? If so, please post the code you wrote till now.[Show your effort! And show your problem!]

Answer (score 4):

When *querying* data (e.g. file lines) *Linq* is often a convenient tool; if the file has lines in

```
name=value
```

format, you can query it like this

1. *Read* file lines
2. *Split* each line into `name, value` pair
3. *Filter* pairs by their names
4. *Extract* value from each pair
5. *Materialize* values into a collection

Code:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// string[] {"Check_Amt", "DBO"}
var values = File 
  .ReadLines(@"c:\MyFile.txt")
  .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2)) // split into name, value pairs
  .Where(items => items.Length == 2)                 // to be on the safe side
  .Where(items => items[0] == "Name")                // name == "Name" only
  .Select(items => items[1])                         // value from name=value
  .ToArray();                                        // let's have an array
```

finally, if you want comma separated `string`, `Join` the `values`:

```
// "Check_Amt,DBO"
string result = string.Join(",", values);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
var str = @"Name=Check_Amt
Public=Yes
DateName=pp
Name=DBO";

var find = "Name=";
var result = new List<string>();
using (var reader = new StringReader(str)) //Change to StreamReader to read from file
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith(find))
            result.Add(line.Substring(find.Length));
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly prefer String.StartsWith to complicated regex solutions or other overengineered things in this simple case. Sure, there's a tool that can do everything else as well, but you dont need it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to select what you need:

```
var names=File. ReadLines("my file.txt" ).Select(l=>l.Split('=')).Where(t=>t.Length==2).Where(t=>t[0]=="Name").Select(t=>t[1])
```

Comment: Voting will be the best appreciation)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best case would be a regex.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?<=Name=).*?(?=Public)";
        string input = @"Name=Check_Amt Public=Yes DateName=pp Name=DBO";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: My answer was written before your question were corrected, while it's still working the LINQ answer would be better IMHO.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I would be grateful if you mark my answer as helpful.